# ¿Cómo obtener cadena enviada mediante método POST?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación donde envió una cadena mediante un método POST a una un controlador genérico (.ashx ), lo que necesitó hacer es obtener esta cadena y asignarla a una variable

Mi código es el siguiente en la página desde donde envió:

```
protected async void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string respuesta = string.Empty;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            string miCadena = CadenaPost();
            StringContent contenido = new StringContent(miCadena, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:50449/CallBackUrlApp.ashx", contenido);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               respuesta = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                respuesta = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
            }

        }

        private string CadenaPost()
        {
         string miCadena = "{ \"clave\":\"50611031800310140886100100001010000000019137761544\",\"fecha\":" +
                "\"20180311T15:19:5606:00\",\"indestado\":\"aceptado\",\"respuestaxml\":" +
                "\"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPE1lbnNhamVIYWNpZW5kYSB4bWxucz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9\" }";
            return miCadena;
        }
```

Y aquí recibo la cadena pero no se como asignarla a una variable de tipo string :

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            if (context.Request.RequestType.Equals("POST") )
            {
                string miCadena = string.Empty;
                //AQUI CODIGO QUE NESCITO PARA ASIGNAR EL CONTENIDO A LA VARIABLE miCadena
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que leer el `Request.InputStream`

```
var stream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
stream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var miCadena = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Hola y gracias hardkoded...en la ultima linea tienes un errorcito corrigelo para q otros usuarios no se confundan ..yo lo pude solventar ...Gracias nuevamente ...

Comment: Listo, perfecto!